# How to align my number-input button in a dynamic position in the page? without use css

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a list of objects, and next to each name I have a vue-number-input, a vue component.

My problem is that every button starts immediately after the name and is not aligned with the others.

How can I align each number-input so that they start from the same position?

Using the classic align = "right" for example, it doesn't work, or rather it works but it puts them all on the right side of the page. Instead I want to have them aligned just next to the names.

Sorry if I was unclear and thank you

!https://github.com/liukct/JS/blob/master/photo.jpg

This is my Template:

```
Vue.component('todo-item', {
    props: ['todo'],
    template: '<li> <div> {{ todo.name }} <vue-numeric-input :value="1" :min="1" :max="100" size="90" align="center"> </vue-numeric-input> </div> </li>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:right` style corresponding to the appropriate selector.